# Passing Multiple IDs During Mass Update

Tags: update, id

Is there a way to create a queue for each Id that is being passed to be processed? I am getting errors when mass updating records with GridBuddy.

```
 trigger Reporting_Data on Forecasting_Data__c(after insert, after update) {

        List<Report_Data__c> data = new List<Report_Data__c>();

        for (Forecasting_Data__c f: Trigger.new) {
            Integer i = Integer.valueOf(f.Fiscal_Year__c);
            Integer rl = Integer.valueOf(f.Related_List_Count__c);
            Date d = Date.newInstance(i, rl + 1, 1);
            if (f.Related_List_Count__c < 12) {
                data.add(new Report_Data__c(Name = f.Name + ' ' + (rl + 1),
                    Forecasting_Data__c = f.Id,
                    Date__c = d));
            }
            insert data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get?  Do you get it for every ID or just some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what specific error you're receiving, but I'll take a guess that your error stems from the fact that you've got a DML statement within a `for` loop.

It appears that your code might just have the `insert` statement in the wrong location.

```
trigger Reporting_Data on Forecasting_Data__c(after insert, after update) {

    List<Report_Data__c> data = new List<Report_Data__c>();

    for (Forecasting_Data__c f: Trigger.new) {
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(f.Fiscal_Year__c);
        Integer rl = Integer.valueOf(f.Related_List_Count__c);
        Date d = Date.newInstance(i, rl + 1, 1);
        if (f.Related_List_Count__c < 12) {
            data.add(new Report_Data__c(Name = f.Name + ' ' + (rl + 1),
                Forecasting_Data__c = f.Id,
                Date__c = d));
        }
        // insert data;
    }

    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        insert data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to click the "accept" checkmark below the voting arrows on the left of my answer. By the way, welcome to the community!